# how do I modify code for an Arduino irrigation project so that it doesn't terminate after 1 demonstration

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using an arduino uno,a soil moisture sensor and a mini water pump ,when the sensor detects insufficient levels of moisture the mini water pump is activated and pumps water until the sensor  records increased moisture eg in soil,this is how it is supposed to work but when I then remove the sensor from the the damp soil water is not pumped again,I have to start running the code again,that's what I need help with,I don't want it to terminate , the code that needs modification is below

```
int relayPin = 8;
int sensor_pin = A0; // Soil Sensor input at Analog PIN A0
int output_value ;
void setup()         // put your setup code here, to run once:
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);                 
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT);
  Serial.println("Reading From the Sensor ...");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop()
{
 output_value= analogRead(sensor_pin);
 output_value = map(output_value,550,10,0,100);
 Serial.print("Mositure : ");
 Serial.print(output_value);
 Serial.println("%");
 if(output_value<20){
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
 }
 else
 {
  digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);       
 }
 delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the soil sensor from the ground, the relay is not expected to operate when the `AN0` analog input will produce a value less than the continuous condition (`< 20`).

```cpp
enum runMode {
  DEBUG,  // When the ground sensor isn't in the ground
  RELEASE // When the ground sensor is in the ground
};

int relayPin = 8;
int sensor_pin = A0;
int output_value;

/* Debug mode has been activated. */
enum runMode mode = DEBUG;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);                 
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT);
  Serial.println("Reading From the Sensor ...");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {  
  output_value= analogRead(sensor_pin);
  output_value = map(output_value,550,10,0,100);
  Serial.println("Mositure: " + String(output_value) + "%");

  if(mode == DEBUG)
    debugMode();
  else
    releaseMode();

  delay(1000);
}

// When debug mode is active, the relay changes position at 1 second intervals
void debugMode() {
  if(digitalRead(relayPin) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);  
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  }
}

// When the release mode is active, the soil sensor must be in the ground.
void releaseMode() {
  if(output_value < 20) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);       
  }
}
```